# Lists returns only the first value

Tags: c#

I have a simple program where I enter names and once I press enter I should get the entered names.

```
var names = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter name");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
       break;
    names.Add(input);
}

if (names.Count == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[0], names[1] + "likes your post");
}
else if (names.Count > 2 )
{
    var number = names.Count;
    Console.WriteLine(names[0], names[1], number + "likes your post");
}
else if (names.Count == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[0] + "likes your post");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("nobody likes your post");
}
```

However, I keep getting back only the first name, not even the "likes your post" part. I have tried to debug it and I always see the right amount of items in the list, but still its wrong.

Could you please point out the issue?

Comment: You could do `string.Join(", ", names)` whenever you have at least one name to get a comma separated list of names to use.  That would work even if you enter more than 2 names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(names[0] + names[1] + "likes your post");
```

**Explanation:**

With the way you had it before, you were (unintentionally) specifying a format string (e.g. `names[0]`) , which isn't what you wanted.

You had:

```
Console.WriteLine(names[0], names[1] + "likes your post");
```

So in the above code, `names[0]` was the format string, and `names[1] + "likes your post"` was the argument used in the format string. But `names[0]` doesn't have any placeholder values (e.g. `{0}, {1}`, etc.) so nothing will get substituted into the format string. So the result is that it will just print `names[0]` by itself.

Here's a more concrete example:

```
string value1 = "Val1";
string value2 = "Val2";
string value3 = "Val3";
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", value1, value2, value3);
```

The `"{0}, {1}, {2}"` is the format string, and the `{0}` means "replace this value with the first argument after the format string", which is `value1` in this example. The `{1}` means "replace this value with the second argument after the format string", which is `value2` in this example.

With the fix, we just removed the format string completely and provided a single argument to `Console.WriteLine`, so it just prints the text verbatim.

Comment: It would really help if you'd explain what was wrong before and why this fixes it - otherwise the OP has no more knowledge about what was going on than they did before.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - done, let me know what you think, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
        var names = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter name");

            var input = Console.ReadLine();


            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                break;
            names.Add(input);

        }

        if (names.Count == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{names[0]}, {names[1]} likes your post");
        }
        else if (names.Count > 2)
        {
            var number = names.Count;
            Console.WriteLine($"{names[0]}, {names[1]}, {number} likes your post");
        }
        else if (names.Count == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{names[0]} likes your post");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nobody likes your post");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) which accepts [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) string and parameters with `names[0]` being the format string.

Try concatenating values like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(names[0] + names[1] + "likes your post") ;
```

Or better (for case when there are two entries in names):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} likes your post", names[0], names[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the string interpolation function of `Console.WriteLine()`.

Your first argument is your string, where you put `{x}` wherever you want a variable to be substituted. Then each further argument will be inserted into your string. The order the arguments are provided determines their `x` index value.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} likes your post",names[0], names[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you also want commas in between viz. Tom, Harry likes your post;
You can use string interpolation. They are always good to use when you've placeholders,like

```
Console.WriteLine($"{names[0]}, {names[1]} likes your post");
```